# Restrict Access to wifi for certain devices

Tags: network, airport

I have high school students and they stay up late at night streaming movies.  I don't want to restrict access for our college student who needs to stay up late to finish papers. Can I select devices that I wish to deny access to?

I have an Airport Extreme hooked through my main computer. I have found where to see the devices that are using the Airport, but I can't identify which computer is which. Anyway, the most important question is can I turn of access to individual devices when I wish to? (Right now I just unplug the wifi.)

Answer (score 1):

You might easily manage this using Timed Access Control settings with a default rule that prohibits wireless internet during off hours.

[image: Airport Utility Timed Access Control]

Then you could set up devices that have exceptions to the rules (or the opposite - block certain devices while letting most clients unfettered access).

To get to the screen above, run Airport Utility and then choose Network and enable Timed Access at the bottom of the visible window.